# Creating PDFs with CSS - body height not being set properly

Tags: html, css, printing, background-image

I'm trying to generate PDFs using [Snappy PDF](https://github.com/knplabs/snappy). It's working great, except I can't specify the heigh of each page. I have variable content length and so I can't say the body needs to be exactly `height: x inches;` Currently the background URL is set to `repeat-y` but for cases where the page break occurs before the natural page break, the background image is clipped and continues on the next page. See the examples below.

This is the first page break:
[image: First Page break]
This is the second page break. Notice that they occur at different points even though the background image is the height of an A4 piece of paper, which the PDF generator is set to use also.
[image: Second page break]

Is there a way of making sure the background image is exactly the height of an A4 piece of paper, regardless of where the page break occurs on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. As it was being designed for fixed dimensions, I absolute positioned everything, and instead of having a background image, I put the image behind the rest of the text but in the HTML.

Not ideal but it's fixed a problem.

The page breaks have become more of an issue though, I'm having to calculate them manually and then force a page break.